# Re-evaluate an expression

Tags: shell

I wanted to re-evaluate the below expression.
The order of execution is as below:

```
export query1="select count(*) from table1 where date='\${file_dt}'"

file_date="20180616"
file_dt=`date -d ${file_date} +'%Y-%m-%d'`
echo $file_dt

>>2018-06-16

echo "$query1"
>>select count(*) from table1 where date='${file_dt}'
```

I wanted the result to be

```
>>select count(*) from table1 where date='2018-06-16'
```

I tried eval echo eval and eval echo. It doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestion please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050), code should be stored in functions -- and a string containing command substitutions or parameter expansions to be evaluated at a later time *is code*. For example:

```
get_query() { echo "select count(*) from table1 where date='${file_dt}'"; }

file_date=20180616
file_dt=$(date -d "$file_date" +%Y-%m-%d)

get_query
```

Of course, you can use `realized_query=$(get_query)` to assign a string based on the current `file_dt` to a variable; should you change the `file_dt`, calling `get_query` again will generate a new query based on the updated value.

---

By the way -- if you're making this into a function, consider passing the date out-of-band. For example:

```
get_query() { echo "select count(*) from table1 where date='$(date -d "$1" +%Y-%m-%d)'"; }
get_query 20180616
```

...because the `date -d` call is part of the function, you can have less concern about SQL injection: No possible input will cause a value that contains a literal `'` or otherwise has undesired effects on the database can be used.

---

It *is* also possible to use `eval`, though risky. See [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) for a discussion of why `eval`-based techniques are best avoided; additional to the usual security concerns, this would cause any literal double-quotes in the string being `eval`uated to be changed to syntactic ones, closing the syntactic ones hardcoded as part of the `eval` string and otherwise causing a mess.

For the sake of completeness, however:

```
# DO NOT DO THIS. Error-prone.

query1="select count(*) from table1 where date='\${file_dt}'"

file_date="20180616"
file_dt=`date -d ${file_date} +'%Y-%m-%d'`

eval "echo \"$query1\""
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign file_dt first and don't escape the file_dt expansion:

```
$ file_date="20180616"
$ file_dt=`date -d ${file_date} +'%Y-%m-%d'`
$ export query1="select count(*) from table1 where date='${file_dt}'"
$ echo "$query1"
select count(*) from table1 where date='2018-06-17'
```

Comment: The `export` doesn't appear to be needed for anything the OP is doing -- it might be worth clarifying that it should only be used if they need subprocesses to find the variable in their environment.